# Accumulation points.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I'm stuck on a question that I'm working on for a problem sheet:

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, with $A\subseteq X$ and $x\in X.$ Show that $x\in\text{cl} A$ iff for every open set $G$ with $x\in G,$ then $G\cap A\neq\emptyset.$

Thus far, I can prove if $X$ is in $\text{cl}A,$ then the intersection is non empty between $A$ and $G$. But I can't seem to prove if $x$ is an element of an arbitrary open set $G$ with  a non empty intersection with $A$ then the point $x$ must be in $\text{cl}A$.
Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Note that $G\cap A\subseteq A\subseteq\overline{A}$

Comment: Thanks, do you think showing there exists an x from G also in A closure is proof enough rather than showing all x in G?